# Top bar not working in foundation 4.3.2 version?

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

in my previous project , i have used the foundation 4 open source. that time i have got a top bar navigation. but now am again  trying new project with foundation. for that i have downloaded http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download-f4.html that is foundation4.3.2 version. i have refereed the foundation 4.3.2 version css and js in my new project, but the top-bar not coming its showing like tree view without any effort of foundation ?

if i refer the foundation 4 , top - bar is working...
  then 
 why Top-bar not working while i refereeing the foundation 4.3.2 version ?

HTML code

```
<html>
<head id="head2" runat="server">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Title" runat="server">
<title>sample project</title>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<link href="../../Scripts/css/foundation.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 <script  src="../../Scripts/js/foundation.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script  src="../../Scripts/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>


<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<img src="../../Scripts/img/logo.png" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 column">
<nav class="top-bar">
<section class="top-bar-section"> 
<ul class="left">
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="has-dropdown">Moderate</li>
<ul class="dropdown">
<li><a href="#">Moderate Posts</a></li>
<li><a href="#">New Post</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Send E-mail</a></li>
</ul>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="has-dropdown">Options</li>
<ul class="dropdown">
<li><a href="#">Statistics</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
</ul>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li class="has-dropdown">Configuration</li>
<ul class="dropdown">
<li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Fields</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Localities</a></li>
<li><a href="#">E-mail Templates</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Admin Users</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>

</section>
</nav>

</div>
</div>

<div class="row" >
    <div class="large-12 columns ">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </div>


<div class="row" >
    <div class="large-12 columns ">
    Copyright @2014 
      </div>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<script src=' +
  ('__proto__' in {} ? '../../Scripts/js/vendor/zepto' : '../../Scripts/js/vendor/jquery') +
  '.js><\/script>')
  </script> 
<script src="../../Scripts/js/foundation.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../../Scripts/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).foundation();


    function setLayout() {
        winWid = $(window).width();
        if (winWid > 750) {
            $(".trd").each(function (index) {
                ht = $(this).height();
                $(this).parent().closest('.row').find('.advt').css('height', ht - 16 + "px");
            })
        }
    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        setTimeout("setLayout()", 1000);
    });

    setLayout()

  </script>






</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: There is no error i found out at run time.. but my web page showing like tree view ( i used ul and li element) without any effort of foundation 4.3.2 version.

My web page should look like below image
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the HTML you are using for your top-bar element as well as any errors being generated in the browser console at run-time?

Comment: @DavidAntaramian , i have added html code . but i didnt get any errors at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
<html>
<head id="head2" runat="server">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Title" runat="server">
        <title>sample project</title>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <link href="../../Scripts/css/foundation.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <img src="../../Scripts/img/logo.png" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 column">
                <nav class="top-bar">
                    <section class="top-bar-section">
                        <ul class="left">
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Moderate</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <li><a href="#">Moderate Posts</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">New Post</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Send E-mail</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Options</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <li><a href="#">Statistics</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Configuration</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Fields</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Localities</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">E-mail Templates</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Admin Users</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns ">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns ">
                Copyright @2014
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write('<script src=' +
                ('__proto__' in {} ? '../../Scripts/js/vendor/zepto' : '../../Scripts/js/vendor/jquery') +
                '.js><\/script>');
        </script>

        <script src="../../Scripts/js/foundation.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).foundation();


            function setLayout() {
                winWid = $(window).width();
                if (winWid > 750) {
                    $(".trd").each(function (index) {
                        ht = $(this).height();
                        $(this).parent().closest('.row').find('.advt').css('height', ht - 16 + "px");
                    })
                }
            }

            $(window).resize(function () {
                setTimeout("setLayout()", 1000);
            });

            setLayout()

        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've done a few things here. First and foremost, I just formatted the code so it could be read easier. Second, I removed the call to `foundation.min.js` in the head. You're calling `foundation.min.js` at the foot of the body, and including it twice can cause confusion with naming variables. I also removed your call to `foundation.topbar.js` because this file is included in the minified script you've already included. Last I re-worked your dropdown menus so that Foundation could interpret them properly. Foundation expects to the dropdown menu to be *within* the parent `li` element. I also made the dropdown `li` text into anchors in accord with Foundation documentation.

Oh, and I added a semi-colon to the `document.write()` statement that includes jQuery/zepto.

Comment: thank you for editing the code and given the explanation for it and that is very useful to me should follow the standard format. i have replaced with your code in my html page, but still no more changes in output. For your Information: am Referring Foudation 4.3.1 version and above i have added  output of my webpage.

Comment: if i use the same html code with refering foundation 4 , am getting the Top-Bar navigation perfectly.

Comment: i found out my mistake in my code.. actually i have made some changes in foundation.css itself.. that made the problem for my web page. after i deleted changes made in the foundation.css , got the top-bar navigation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not foundation 4.3.2 version problem. actually i have made some changes in foundation.css itself.. that made the problem for my web page. after i deleted changes made in the foundation.css then got the top-bar navigation.

**So we dont  make changes in the foundation.css itself.
better we can create customized css for our references.**